# Convert U.S. TDateTime value to correctly dispay in European format

Tags: delphi, tdatetime, formatdatetime

Is there any simple option to convert a U.S. `TDateTime` value **Apr 17, 2014 8:35:38 PM PDT** to a European format looking like **2014-04-17 20:35:38**?

EDIT:

I have a string containing raw date/time in U.S. format:

```
var s, new_s: string;
begin
  s := 'Apr 17, 2014 8:35:38 PM PDT';
```

I want to somehow read/parse this string to a variable of `TDateTime` type *-or-* just convert it to another string of the desired format:

```
  new_s := MyConvertDateTimeSring(s);
  // now new_s must be '2014-04-17 20:35:38';
end;
```

(Delphi XE4)

Comment: There is no global *European format*. For instance we're using format like 17.4.2014 20:35:38 in Czech locale. The format is per country.

Comment: You understand that the `TDateTime` variable isn't really in *either* of those formats, right? You can format the date using whatever string format you want.

Comment: Your question is surely how to parse a date/time *string* to a date *value*.

Comment: @TLama I do not mean any ***global European format***. Many locales assume different separators. In fact, I just want to get rid of the U.S. format. So any conversion to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss will make me happy.

Comment: @RobKennedy how do I do that?

Comment: Rob is talking about `TDateTime` and you are talking about a string containing some symbols that represent a date, time and timezone (we now know after your edit)

Comment: Also, which European country writes dates like that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my SQL Server does :)
I guess the solution is to parse the string and assemble the date in the format I need. Cause if there were a easier solution you would have told me ;)

Comment: Don't pass text to database. Don't store dates as text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't, David. I use 8 bytes `datetime` type. Thanks for mentioning this. My SQL Server's stored procedures eat different parameters of datetime type. `exec myStoredProc '2014-04-17 20:21:22'` works the same way as `17.04.2014` and `17/04/2014`. The only unaccepted format is the subject of the question.

Comment: You should answer to questions more accurate. DH: "which ... writes dates like that?" OP: "my SQL Server does" and now you are telling that you want to store that information into sql server, you did not receive this from there ...

Comment: @SirRufo My question is not about SQL Server. It is about parsing a data string into a desired datetime *value* (as David mentioned above). And you perfectly answered that. Nobody cares how I use the string when it is correctly formatted ;) THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the TimeZone *PDT* from the string then you can use [`VarToDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Variants.VarToDateTime) to convert the string into a `TDateTime` value

```
var
  LDateTimeStr : string;
  LDateTime : TDateTime;
begin
  LDateTimeStr := 'Apr 17, 2014 8:35:38 PM PDT';
  LDateTime := VarToDateTime( Copy( LDateTimeStr, 1, 23 ) );
  WriteLn( FormatDateTime( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', LDateTime ) );
end;
```

The result will be

> 2014-04-17 20:35:38

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. `VarToDateTime` and `FormatDateTime` will be my evening reading for tonight :)
In fact `LDateTime := VarToDateTime(Copy(LDateTimeStr, 1, Pos(' PDT', LDateTimeStr)));` will be a bit more accurate since there might be Apr 7 instead of Apr 17.

Comment: That time zone portion might be very crucial information here.

Comment: @TLama Thats right, but this is not part of this question ;o)